# How should I calculate the commutator between the Belinfante stress tensor and the field operator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, ward-identity

As known, there is an ambiguity on the definition of the stress tensor (or energy-momentum tensor).

The canonical stress tensor, defined as the Noether's current corresponding to space-time translational invariance, is $T^{\mu\nu}_{can.}=\partial\mathcal L/\partial(\partial_\mu \phi_l)\partial^\nu\phi_l-g^{\mu\nu}\mathcal L$, whose $\mu\nu$ indicies are not necessarily symmetric.

The Belinfante-Rosenberg stress tensor, defined as the variation of action over the metric, i.e., $T^{\mu\nu}_{B.R.}=\delta S / \delta g_{\mu\nu}$, is symmetric on the $\mu\nu$ indices.

The canonical stress tensor obeys the canonical commuational relation, i.e., $$[T^{0\mu}(x),\phi_l(y)]\delta(x^0-y^0)=\partial^\mu\phi_l(x)\delta^4(x-y),$$ which is crucial for deriving the gravitational Ward Identity.

I wonder, if how should I generalize the above commutational relation for the Belinfante-Rosenberg Stress tensor, so that I can obtain the Ward Identity accordingly.